# AngularJS - A function to return value, if there is no value, return nothing within the cell

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, pdfmake

I am exporting table data as a pdf using pdfmake.
Depending if there a value set within the table, based on what is filtered within the Search dropdowns, I want to return that value.  Otherwise I want to return ''.

As of now if nothing is set within the cell it will return as 'null' I want to return '' instead of null.

Here is the expression I am using from the html

```
<td style="background-color: #bfdfff; word-wrap: break-word;" class="routeCheckInGrid">
    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_RouteCheckIn_Editable1_lblAccidentMcGoal">{{monday.accidentFreeDayMCG}} /day</span>
</td>
```

Tried creating a function that gives me the value or returns ' '.
scope.drivers is where all the data is set.

```
$scope.accidentFreeMC = function(monday) { 
        if ($scope.drivers) {
            if ($scope.resultsRolledUp) {
                return monday.accidentFreeDayMCG;
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
    }
```

using it in the table

```
table: {
         body: [
                  [                          
                    $scope.accidentFreeMC + ' /day',
                  ],    
         ]
}
```

What am i missing?  Any help is much appreciated.

UPDATE**
Here is a working example of something similar that I would like to achieve.
Here is a row where depending on what Route is filtered in the search, will show data in the total column.  If a specific Route is selected then nothing is shown in the cell.

```
$scope.wasTheLCPAuditCompleted = function(day) {
    if ($scope.drivers) {
        if ($scope.resultsRolledUp) {
            return day.lcpAuditCompletedCount + '/' + day.dayRouteCount
        }

        if (!$scope.resultsRolledUp && (!$scope.dataEntryView || $scope.isRollup)) {
            return day.lcpAuditCompleted == 'Y' ? 'Yes' : 'No';
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: from the HTML you call it {{accidentFreeMc()}} . From the controller: $scope.accidentFreeMc();

Comment: Yes the expression is defined in the html as {{monday.accidentFreeDayMCG}}.  And the function I am trying to create is $scope.accidentFreeMC.  Similar but different.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is `monday` defined on the `$scope`?  I say this because you reference it here:  `{{monday.accidentFreeDayMCG}}`.  Is it a local variable in an `ngRepeat`?

Comment: It is not in an ngRepeat

Comment: I have updated the original question with some code of an example that does something similar to what I want.  Please see above

Comment: You need to do `{{monday.accidentFreeDayMCG()}}` in your template. Without the `()` the function is not invoked at all. Same for table `$scope.accidentFreeMC() + ' /day'`